# How do I use sscanf() to parse this line of text?

Tags: c, string, parsing, scanf

I have this line of text I want to analyse, for example: "A,B(C10D)" and after parsing, it should print out something like:

```
value 1: A
value 2: B
value 3: C10D
```

As you can see, I have two delimiters: a comma and the open and close brackets ().

This is the code I have written so far, with the assistance of other answers on Stack Overflow threads, but it doesn't seem to work...

```
char text[100] = "A,B(C10D)";
sscanf(text,"%s,%s(%s)",val1,val2,val3);

printf("Value 1: %s\n", val1);
printf("Value 2: %s\n", val2);
printf("Value 3: %s\n", val3);
```

Is there something wrong with my format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` scans until a *whitespace* character (or `EOF`).

Use the `%[` format specifier to parse your string:

```
sscanf(text, "%[^,],%[^(](%[^)])", val1, val2, val3);
```

`%[^,]` would scan everything *until* a `,`
`,` will consume the comma since `%[^,]` will not consume it
`%[^(]` would scan everything *until* a `(`
`(` will consume the left bracket since `%[^(]` will not consume it
etc

---

Always check the return value of `sscanf`. `sscanf` returns the number of arguments successfully read and assigned.

```
int retVal = sscanf(text,"%[^,],%[^(](%[^)])", val1, val2, val3);
if(retVal == 3)
{
    /* Scanned and assigned all three arguments successfully */
}
else if(retVal == EOF)
{
    /* EOF was encountered */
}
else
{
    /* Invalid input; parsing error */
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I really needed that simple explanation you provided. So, just to be clear, this approach would only work if there are no whitespaces in the string, right? Or is something like: `"%[^ ] %[^(](%[^)])"` work too?

Comment: @Tina Yes. But you can tell `sscanf` to skip all whitespace by inserting a single space in the format string in the position where you want to skip over them

Comment: @Tina Yes. `%[^ ] %[^(](%[^)])` will work as expected too. It will read everything until a space, and then read everything until a `(` and then everything until a `)`